# How to assign robot framework global variable to another variable in another robotfile

Tags: robotframework

I have assigned global variable as ${googlesite} = http://google.com and I want to use this variable in another robot file under variable section as

robot1.robot

```
${googlesite} = http://google.com

*** keywords ***

set suite variable ${googlesite}
```

robot2.robot

```
*** Variables ***

${googlelogin} = ${googlesite}/login.html


*** Keywords ***
log to console ${googlesite}-- Its printing as http://google.com

log to console ${googlelogin}-- printing only ./login.html
```

(not appending ${googlesite} from variables section)

Comment: The syntax of your code isn't correct. You don't have enough whitespace after the `=`. Also, `robot1.robot` is defining a keyword named `set suite variable ${googlesite}` which is probably not what you're intending. Are you certain that _this_ code will reproduce your problem? Please provide a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by executing the variable assignment using a keyword.

So in `robot1.robot`, define a keyword to set this variable:

```
*** Keywords ***
Setup
    Set Global Variable    ${googlesite}    http://google.com
```

Then import `robot1.robot` in `robot2.robot` as a resource and execute the Setup keyword anywhere before accessing the variable:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource          robot1.robot

Suite Setup       Setup

*** Test Cases ***
Test global variable

    # The global variable is available in robot2.robot
    log to console    ${googlesite}
    # Use it to form the new variable
    ${googlelogin} =    Convert To String     ${googlesite}/login.html
    log to console    ${googlelogin}
```

This will print:

```
Test global variable                                                  http://google.com
http://google.com/login.html
| PASS |
```

Comment: You can do that step as a `Suite Setup` and will work for all tests in that suite. Once the variable is set it will be available from then on for all tests until robot stops. I have edited the response with this solution.

Comment: This works but looking for option under Variables

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how the code you've provided is working at all given you're using log to consoles directly in keywords section and all the spacing is wrong.

You can import robot1.robot into robot2.robot and robot2.robot will have access without the need to set it as a suite variable.

robot1.robot:

```
*** Variables ***
${googlesite}   http://google.com
```

robot2.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource  robot1.robot

*** Variables ***
${googlelogin}   ${googlesite}/login.html

*** Test Cases ***
Check the Google variables are correct
    log to console  \nGoogle Site: ${googlesite}
    log to console  Google Login: ${googlelogin}
```